# Unable to access nested property of array of static class

Tags: c#, arrays, class, nested-properties

Givens:

1. The class must be accessible from inside another class that must be static (no choice).
2. The FOO class must be recursable supporting a nested array of a collection of items given the structure in the example.
3. FOO must be serializable in full including all nested arrays and subsequent items inclusive to XML (without using fancy tricks -- just straight serialize to xml which seems to support only one class and will auto-find nested classes / structures accordingly)

---

The problem is I can not do the following as the properties of FOOTabItem are not accessible.

```
// can not be static
public class TestClass : SomeFancyInheritedObject { 

    // must be static
    public static void Test() {
        FOO.FOOTabItem bar = new FOOTabItem();

        bar.Count = 100;  // This is inaccessible
    }

}
```

This is the class code I am having trouble making the objects exposed from :

```
public static class FOO {
    public static int Money { get; set; }

    public static List<FOOTab> Tabs { get; set; }


    public static struct FOOTab {
        public static List<FOOTabItem> Items { get; set; }

        public static FOOTab TabInformation { get; set; }
    }

    public static struct FOOTabItem {
        public static ItemInfo Item { get; set; }
        public static int Count { get; set; }

    }

    public static FOO() {
        Tabs = new List<FOOTab>();
        Money = 0;
    }

}
```

I have also tried using nested classes instead of `struct` in FOO, however this resulted in FOO complaining that I can not use a class as an object parameter which is why I am using `struct` instead.

There are no syntax errors with this code. I can expose the properties/etc of FOO itself and instantiate `new()` of the structs, however I can not see the properties of the structs.

I believe this is likely a permissions issue (public / static / internal / etc), but I am unsure what exactly to do to correct this.  I have searched SO and there are issues similar in nature however they do not offer any clear insight regarding nested Lists of objects inside static classes and how to properly access them from within other static classes.

Comment: You have a lot of issues in your code.  Why must TestClass.Test() be static? Why are FOOTab and FooTabItem static structs?  In TestClass.Test() you are trying to create a new instance of FOO.FOOTabItem(), you can't instantiate a static class.

Comment: Will give the short explanation.  TestClass.Test() is a static override and must be so due to the way the developer wrote the actual method being inherited from.  I have obfuscated and used 'Test' and 'Foo' and 'Bar' for a more classical representation of the problem at hand.  Further, I have found why the properties of the structures were not being exposed was because even though the struct must be 'static' to be visible inside static methods, the properties should not have 'static' as this prevents exposure.

Comment: Additionally, while downvoting is a fantastic feature, if you are down-voting simply because you can not understand or do not like what you see that really shows maturity and is counter-productive to what the feature is actually there for. It is not a like/dislike option. It is a vote on the quality of research, and clarity of the question.

Comment: bar.Count is inaccessible because you are treating FOOTabItem as an instance type, which it is not.  FOO.FOOTabItem.Count = 100; will be valid as you are then accessing a static property in a static struct in a static class.

Comment: As to point 3: FOO is not serializable as static classes are not serializable.

Comment: This compiles for you?  I get the error that static is not valid on the structs.

Comment: ok, so any suggestions on how to do this the right way ?   thats why i posted the question.  I need something accessible from inside a static method that has the capability of hosting multiple collections of multiple structure types which can be easily serialized to xml.

Comment: @KyleW - I think it depends on how your IDE is setup.  For me, it was allowing static inside the structs without giving any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed all the static keywords in the code below.  Here, bar.Count is accessible.

```
public class TestClass : SomeFancyInheritedObject 
{ 
    public static void Test() {
        FOO.FOOTabItem bar = new FOO.FOOTabItem();
        bar.Count = 100; // This is now accessible
    }
}
public class FOO {
    public int Money { get; set; }
    public List<FOOTab> Tabs { get; set; }

    public FOO() {
        Tabs = new List<FOOTab>();
        Money = 0;
    }

    public struct FOOTab {
        public List<FOOTabItem> Items { get; set; }
        public FOOTab()
        {
            Items = new List<FOOTabItem>();
        }
    }

    public struct FOOTabItem {
        public ItemInfo Item { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
In response to your comment, here is code that I've tested in VS:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new FOO();
        var x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FOO));
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                x.Serialize(writer, foo);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class FOO
{
    public int Money { get; set; }
    public List<FOOTab> Tabs { get; set; }

    public FOO()
    {
        Tabs = new List<FOOTab>();
        Money = 0;
    }

    public class FOOTab
    {
        public List<FOOTabItem> Items { get; set; }
        public FOOTab()
        {
            Items = new List<FOOTabItem>();
        }
    }

    public class FOOTabItem
    {
        public ItemInfo Item { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
}

public class ItemInfo
{
}
```

Comment: This is what I found worked as well.   Just finished doing that before replying above.  Still unsure why I can't serialize it as it moans about the subtypes >>  System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type.

Comment: I've changed the structs to classes, as structs should really be immutable.  And added code that shows it being serialised.

Comment: Not sure why, but even after adjustments, I am getting a reflection error on this line >> `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer=new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer( typeof( MyNameSpace.FOO ) );` stating the above error.  Surfing SO for this, but not coming up with anything.  Is it possible that the parent software is blocking reflection ?

Comment: Found the nasty bean i believe is root of this problem.  Not sure how to correct it since I don't have source of the parent program >
`ItemInfo cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor`   ---  that is an object from parent software.

Comment: That is correct, a serializable object needs to have an parameterless constructor.  But all is not lost.  If you cannot get the ItemInfo code changed you can still "serialize" by creating a wrapper object for ItemInfo that is serializable.  Will depend on what ItemInfo looks like though

Comment: Sorry for the delay, was just working on that.  It has quite a number of parameters.  Would be nice to be able to inherit structures to add the additional method with no params as required, or to simply pass a couple params so reflection can understand what the object looks like.